# Padlock on a downloaded PS5 game

Tags: ps4, backwards-compatibility, ps5

So, I bought a PS4 game in 2017 that was removed from the PlayStation Store a few years later. It doesn’t even show up in my transaction history, weirdly enough, and I obviously don’t have the order number, since it has been so long.

I moved it to an external HD and plugged it into my PS5. Bizarrely, the game shows up as downloaded, but has a padlock next to it, and doesn’t allow me to play it.

Is there any way around this? Or am I forced to play it on my PS4 only? The only solutions I found to the “padlock” issue regarded redownloading…

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From experience, the padlock icon means it's not able to validate the license. Perhaps the game was purchased from a different account on the PS4?

Comment: I’ll triple-check, but I’m almost positive I only have one profile with a linked PSN account on my PS4…

Comment: Dumb question, have you tried rebooting? Sometimes that happens to me with no reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, long story short, @Wondercricket was right. It turns out I had two accounts on my PS4, one of which purchased quite literally **every single game** besides this one (for no reason I can recall...).

It was actually quite the headache, because this other account was tied to an email which no longer existed, so, after a couple hours with customer support, I got everything to work! Thank you for the suggestion, @pinckerman, and thank you @Wondercricket for what turned out to be the solution!

Comment: Glad you solved the issue!